# Not able to install Devkit in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting bellow error when trying to install Devkit in Windows 8.1

```
C:\1\Devkit\DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.3.1 at C:/Ruby23
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.3.3 at C:/Ruby23-x64
```

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

can any one pls help, I tried to uninstall and reinstall Ruby and Devkit , but still getting error.

When running feature file on Rubymine,  error "No SDK specified"

My config.yml file is

```
# This configuration file contains the absolute path locations of all
# installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the DevKit. This config
# file is generated by the 'ruby dk.rb init' step and may be modified
# before running the 'ruby dk.rb install' step. To include any installed
# Rubies that were not automagically discovered, simply add a line below
# the triple hyphens with the absolute path to the Ruby root directory.
#
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---
- C:/Ruby22-x64
- C:/Ruby23
```

Comment: It seems you have two Ruby versions installed and then you must declare what SDK you are using.

Comment: Yes, Its true, i have two versions, but I have deleted both versions and installed 2.3.3 64 bit version, Deleted Devkit and installed latest Devkit too, I am still having same error, could u pls let me know how to delete other version

Comment: Would you kindly edit your question and post the directories where you installed 2.3.3 64bit version and Devkit now? Besides, post the contents of your devkir/config.yml file, please. This way it will be easier for me to say what is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Please find the config.yml

Comment: # This configuration file contains the absolute path locations of all
# installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the DevKit. This config
# file is generated by the 'ruby dk.rb init' step and may be modified
# before running the 'ruby dk.rb install' step. To include any installed
# Rubies that were not automagically discovered, simply add a line below
# the triple hyphens with the absolute path to the Ruby root directory.
#
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---
- C:/Ruby22-x64
- C:/Ruby23

Comment: Please remove the line `C:/Ruby22-x64` and try again. I think it is getting confused by the fact you have two lines here.

Comment: if i remove and run again, but config.yml is creating same file with Ruby22-64  file, I tried to uninstall Ruby22-64  , now Rubyis not even recognizing

Comment: I really don't know what is happening. Did you have any progress? If not, may I suggest you to install a VM with Linux and use it for Ruby and RoR development?